# My employer is postponing my FIRST paycheck due to a funding shortfall; what can I do?

Tags: salary, startup

I don't think I can even file for unemployment or can I? I'm continuing to work and attend meetings. It seems like a bad idea for me to be actively checking code into their source control system if I'm not getting paid. It's a startup seeking additional venture capital. I also haven't been reimbursed for flying to their headquarters to work for a few days.

CA unemployment says I'm performing work for someone so ineligible. I'm applying elsewhere, but I have to pay rent and other bills long before I can get a check from someone else. If I quit and start work full time, I think I become ineligible.

Comment: Check your contract, was there any agreement even informal that you may have to wait on funds? If not then they have to pay you.

Comment: @Killsi The employment agreement says nothing about delays in payment.

Comment: Go get your money then

Comment: @Killsi I don't think it's that easy.

Comment: It never is, but you need to be direct as in Joes answer, and proactive if the response isn't acceptable.

Comment: So which organization will help me with getting paid? Do I need to go to the Department of Labor? Do I hire an attorney?

Comment: Is it clear to you that you should be looking for a new job?

Comment: Yes, I’m frantically applying, but it can take months to get through background checks to a start date to an actual check after 2 weeks to a month of work. Meanwhile, I have worked a month of long hours as a supposedly salaried employee and my rent and other essentials are due on the 1st. I need to raise significant funds or I will be homeless, car-less and in a world of hurt a few days from now.  I hoped that I could claim unemployment since I’m looking for work and there’s no actual income excluding the worthless stock options they’ve offered to trade for my salary.

Comment: It won't help you at this point, but this is why having at least a month's equivalent salary in a savings account is advisable. Also (and maybe of help), another answer on this forum within the last week stated that some local laws will heavily punish a company which does not pay its staff. (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/147159/93518).

Comment: @Justin I had 6 months worth of reserve. The hiring cycle for software engineering managers is quite long, with background checks, many rounds of interviews, and limited numbers of positions. Then these guys said they would have to give me RSU for the first two weeks.

Comment: As a side-note: you don't need to wait for work in your preferred field, and if you absolutely *need* money in the immediate term (as it sounds like you do) and your field's hiring processes are slow, then you *can't* wait for work that exactly suits your tastes. Getting a *paying* temporary job can sustain you through the slow hiring process in your preferred field. Money.SE might be a good resource for options until the checks start coming in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My employer is postponing my FIRST paycheck due to a funding shortfall; what can I do?

Postpone any work for this company until they have paid you for your work and have been reimbursed for your business travel.  If you have not been paid within a week, report them to your state's Attorney General.  Finally, start looking for a new company to work for.  If I were you, I would avoid startups as they are usually not very stable with regards to financials and a normal working environment.

Comment: Your state's Department of Labor would also be a good place to contact if you have not been paid for work performed.

Comment: "If I were you, I would avoid startups" I think this is going a smidge too far. Startups can be great but you should know what you are getting into.

Answer (score 22):

> I don't think I can even file for unemployment or can I?

You cannot file for or collect unemployment while you are employed.

And in general, you cannot collect unemployment benefits if you quit. But check with your state's unemployment office to see if you can collect unemployment benefits if you quit in your specific circumstances. Do this *before* you decide to quit. Only your state's office can actually determine your eligibility.

You can ask your employer when you can expect to get paid.

If you don't get a good answer, you can call your local Department of Labor and State Attorney General's office.

Meanwhile, you can try hard to get your next job with a company who can actually pay their employees.

Comment: If they have already missed a pay date, and they have failed to reimburse him as promised for his air travel, and it sounds as though they have, OP should talk to the California Labor and Workforce Development Agency as soon as he/she possibly can, if only to get their advice and give them a heads-up that he may be needing their help in the very near future.  State employment commissions in the US have a LOT of power to pull employers into line, and they are in general not the slightest bit shy or hesitant about wielding that power, when they deem it appropriate.

Comment: If they are not paying the OP then they are not employed that's basic frustration of contract law 101

Comment: I would have thought that contract law is the same in the USA as the UK, I suspect the OP gave the SS office grounds for refusing - the OP still thinks they are employed and said as much

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if you quit your job because you haven't been paid you can collect unemployment benefit in every jurisdiction I've encountered.

Comment: I can confirm what @DJClayworth said, usually this comes down to "constructive dismissal". Not being paid is a very clear and strong reason for constructive dismissal.

Answer (score 2):

No, the accepted answer is not really correct.

It's not the State Attorney General. It will be quicker if you file directly with the Labor Commissioner's Office of California.

> File a claim for unpaid wages with the Labor Commissioner’s Office.
>   https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/HowToFileWageClaim.htm

The advice to stop work is good also.

Also, if they're not paying you and you quit because of that, it's not really quitting, it's them breaching your employment contract. So check on your unemployment eligibility.

But like you said, if you're able to find another full time job right away, unemployment won't kick in. From what I remember, it takes at least one week to start from the time you've stopped working, plus one additional week for you to receive your first paycheck.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, That's why I said "from the time you've stopped working". Before the time he stopped working, that's the responsibility of the Labor Department/Agency and the Labor Commissioner’s Office may even advance him the wages he's owed if the company doesn't come through (but I do not know if they'll reimburse him his traveling expenses).

Comment: Also, "advance" is the wrong word, because even if they can't recover the money from the original company, the Labor agency will take the hit financially, because by law, the agency is ultimately liable for stolen wages if the original employer can't pay.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere interesting comments but what where the questions?

Comment: The point about reporting the non-payment is spot on. However, "revoke them access to any resources that are still under your ownership" _could_ be dangerous advice. Absolutely _do not_ hold anything ransom that belongs to your employer, such as code you wrote for them but stored in a private repository - that is legally theirs, even if they did not pay you for it, and keeping it could land you in hot water.Just report them and go job hunting.

Comment: @sleske, Point taken.